# ggplot in plotly behaves differently

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I made a plot using following code in ggplot. Here is the data source
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzauims7rqwurga/who_ghg_complete.csv?dl=0

```js
p1 <- ghg_complete %>% 
  filter(`Country Name` %in% c("United States", "China", "India")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = Emissions, 
             group = `Country Name`, color = `Country Name`)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 21) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Greenhouse gas emissions (kt of CO2 equivalent)",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1970, 2012, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
p1
```

Here is the output:-
[image]
When I wrap the same plot in ggplotly

```
ggplotly(p1)
```

The plot behaves differently. The legends don't look the same and the numbers in y-axis is clipped off.
[image]

I changed the y-axis numbering as suggested in comments that still didn't help with the issue.
Here is the code:

```
p1 <- ghg_complete %>% 
  filter(`Country Name` %in% c("United States", "China", "India", "Nepal")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = Emissions, 
             group = `Country Name`, color = `Country Name`)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 21) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Greenhouse gas emissions (kt of CO2 equivalent)",
       x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1970, 2012, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
# Convert ggplot object to plotly
gg <- plotly_build(p1) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', y = -0.1))
gg
```

Here is the plot:-
[image]

Comment: That is just how legends are in plotly. Don't think you can do much about it. And while the clipping is a bug, wouldn't you be better off with units of megaton or gigaton? That is too many zeros for my old eyes.

Comment: @MikeWise is not your eyes... There are too many Zeros to be understandable... Or maybe my eyes are old too :-)

Comment: Additionally: why do you expect plotly to give you the same results as your tailored ggplot plot?

Comment: What is with the useless code snippets all over the place now? Useless because they are Javascript only...

Comment: I converted the units but that didn't help with the y-axis numbers. Any suggestions? Is there a better way to make ggplot plots interactive without using plotly.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplotly()` doesn't exactly copy your ggplot graph into plotly, it makes a plotly equivalent. If you want to make sure your plotly graph looks like your ggplot graph you will need to adjust it further in plotly. For example to get the legend to look more alike you can add `%>% layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.35, y = -0.1))` to your `ggplotly` call. You might have to tweak the `x` and `y` values to line the legend up exactly as you like.

As Mike Wise suggests in the comments for the clipping of the axis labels, you're probably better off just representing the values in megatons or gigatons so that they don't have so many 0s

Comment: Thanks, @Marijn Stevering that helped with the legend.